# PayPal omit Pay Later button with JS SDK

Tags: paypal

Using the new Javascript SDK with paypal.buttons ("smart buttons"), is there a way to omit the Pay Later button? It's not an option using the disable-funding parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> It's not an option using the disable-funding parameter.

Why is it not an option for you? `&disable-funding=paylater` is exactly the way.